# How to fix error with xcodebuild in GitHub Actions

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, github-actions

I'm trying to setup a CI with my private Swift project in Github using GitHub Actions. I've used the standard swift.yml template provided by Github with some modifications. Here is the file `ci.yml`

```
name: Swift

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Run tests
      run: xcodebuild -project 'MyApp.xcodeproj' -scheme 'MyApp' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,OS=13.2' clean test
    - name: Build App
      run: xcodebuild -project 'MyApp.xcodeproj' -scheme 'MyApp' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -configuration Release build CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

When I push a new build to the repo the action triggers but it is failing at the test.

```
xcodebuild -project 'MyApp.xcodeproj' -scheme 'MyApp' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,OS=latest' clean test
```

I ran locally and all tests pass. On GitHub Actions I'm presented with this error

```
Set up job                  0s
Run actions/checkout@v1     2s
Run tests                   34s
    ##[error]Process completed with exit code 70.
1     Run xcodebuild -project 'MyApp.xcodeproj' -scheme 'MyApp' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,OS=13.2' clean test
4        xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
5             { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:13.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
6
9        Ineligible destinations for the "MyApp" scheme:
10           { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
11           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }
12    ##[error]Process completed with exit code 70.
Build App                   0s
Complete job
```

This test should be passing. I'm not sure how to fix this an move forward so the Action no longer fails

Comment: looks like there is no installed exactly this simulator on Github build server

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/unipheas/Numero) is using the exact same build file and it works. Am I missing something inside my project or a Github setting I should enable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this error by forcing Xcode 11. I used the following code to make it work. All tests are now passing and everything works.

```
name: Swift

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Force Xcode 11
      run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.3.app
    - name: Run tests
      run: xcodebuild clean test -project "MyApp.xcodeproj" -scheme "MyApp" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,OS=latest"
    - name: Build App
      run: xcodebuild -project "MyApp.xcodeproj" -scheme "MyApp" -destination "generic/platform=iOS" -configuration Release build CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

Comment: I got the following error: xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode_11.3.app'